# Number of solutions in system of linear equations

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

---

I'm studying System of linear equations.

When solving `Ax=b`, it is said that the system can behave in 3 ways.

- No solution
- Unique solution
- Infinitely many solutions

And according to Wikipedia page,

> Usually, a system with fewer equations than unknowns has **infinitely many solutions, but it may have no solution**. Such a system is known as an underdetermined system.
>
> Usually, a system with the same number of equations and unknowns has **a single unique solution**.
>
> Usually, a system with more equations than unknowns has **no solution**. Such a system is also known as an overdetermined system.

I think the word `Usually` implies that the system can behaves in 3 ways for any arbitrary matrices(it does not care the matrix is a square matrix or non-square matrix).

I want to know the possible behaviors when the matrix A is non-square.

My questions are

1. Can non-square matrices(m < n) have a unique solution(unknowns > equations)?
2. Can non-square matrices(m > n) have infinitely many solutions(unknowns < equations)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. No. $m<n$ $\Rightarrow$ $\text{rank} A\le m<n$ $\Rightarrow$ $\dim\ker A=n-\text{rank} A\ge n-m>0$.
2. Yes. For example, $0_{m\times n}x=0_{m\times 1}$, i.e. $m>n$ many trivial ($0=0$) equations.

In general,

- *no solution* is always a possibility (e.g. one equation looks like $0=1$).
- *$\infty$ many solutions* is always a possibility (e.g. one can add as many trivial equations $0=0$ as one wishes).
- *Unique solution* is possible only for $m\ge n$.